# Properly define variables using input statement

Tags: sas

How can I change all the column to `$8.`?

Below is my code

```
data workout; 
input Day1-Day7 $8. ;  
datalines;`   
chest leg back rest chest leg back;      
run;
```

And the result only show the last column `Day7` with `back` and other column just show `.` only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your code will likely not produce any output. The semicolon `;` ending the data enumeration should be located on a **separate** line, not on the same line as your records.

Secondly, only `Day7` has a value because it is the only variable that you specify as character. Make sure to use parenthesis around the type and length and use the colon `:` modifier to tell SAS to read the variables until there is a space or delimiter `(:$8.)`.

Also, the `run;` at the end is not needed, but does not harm any ;)

```
data workout;
input (Day1-Day7) (:$8.);
datalines;
chest leg back rest chest leg back
;
```

```
chest leg back rest chest leg back
```